# Node js download csv file and notify response in browser

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, csv

Hello currently I m working on a `MEAN-Stack` applicaiton `Node` and `Angular1`

My task is to export `JSON` to `csv` and to download it.

I am using [Json2csv](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv) Plugin.

Here is the code I applied,

```
exports.exportCsv = function(req, res, next) {
  var users = req.body.users;
  if (users.length > 0) {
    var fields = ['_id', 'firstName', 'email'];
    try {
      var result = json2csv({ data: users, fields: fields });
      var path = Date.now() + '.csv';
      fs.writeFile(path, result, function(err, resu) {
        if (err) {
          return ext.returnError(res, err, 500);
        } else {
          res.download(path);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  } else {
    console.error('error');
  }
};
```

This code works fine and the file is getting downloaded but,

**I can't see in browser that it is getting downloaded. 
How to I send the response to browser so that it gets downloaded as all other files get.**

How do the user get noticed that the file got downloaded. The file is getting download without showing in downloads.

Comment: Downvote as soon as the question is asked? Atleast please read the question first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
res.download(path);
res.status(201).send('downloaded');
```

And then check the error code or response message in API call on frontend.

Comment: thanks for the response. Actually, I was able to download the file from my code. no error was coming. But the file is downloaded automatically without notifying the browser. Is there any way to show the download process in browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i am no sure what you got as res but to be sure, look on it.

```
 else {
      res.download(path);
      res.msg = "ok ...";
      alert(res);//object res
      //wich attributes property got res (show us)
      for(var i in res){
         console.log(i);//attr
         console.log(res[i]);//value
      }
      alert(res.msg);//res from us inside js
    }
```

Comment: here `res` is the `express js` response object.

Comment: So you known where find this object and add after the upload a message to send to your express as response in the object res, look at the documentation or readme of this package.

Comment: Actually, I was able to download the file from my code. The csv data is returned back. But the file is downloaded automatically without notifying the browser. Is there any way to show the download process in browser.